# Java regex: match expression delimited by whitespaces

Tags: java, regex

Phone number is like:

```
+38097-12-34-123
+380971234-123
380971234-123
```

I should match phone numbers in string assuming that they separated by whitespaces. So this is not matched strings:

```
45+38097-12-34-123
+38097-12-34-123=TEST
my number:38097-12-34-123
```

Working regex for phone number without whitespace delimiter requirements is:

```
\\+?380\\d\\d(?:-?\\d){7}
```

I try tests with `\b` / `\B` [boundary matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) but they don't work if leading `+` sign was used.

**UPDATE** I fixed examples because I type it from memory and forget to put `8` sign.

**UPDATE2** **@Washington Guedes** Your regex (I strip `\` from `\-`):

```
\b(\+?\d{4}(?:-\d{2}-|\d{2})\d{2}-\d{3})\b
```

doesn't work because when `+` in matching string:

```
bash# groovysh 
groovy:000> "45 +8097-12-34-123".matches(".*\\b(\\+?\\d{4}(?:-\\d{2}-|\\d{2})\\d{2}-\\d{3})\\b.*")
===> true
groovy:000> "45+8097-12-34-123".matches(".*\\b(\\+?\\d{4}(?:-\\d{2}-|\\d{2})\\d{2}-\\d{3})\\b.*")
===> true
```

I expect that expession without whitepsace before `+` sign should fail.

**@stribizhev** Same with your suggestion:

```
groovy:000> "45+38097-12-34-123".matches(".*(?<!\\w)\\+?380\\d\\d(?:-?\\d){7}(?!\\w).*")
===> true
groovy:000> "45 +38097-12-34-123".matches(".*(?<!\\w)\\+?380\\d\\d(?:-?\\d){7}(?!\\w).*")
===> true
```

Comment: Try this regex: `\b(\+?\d{4}(?:\-\d{2}\-|\d{2})\d{2}\-\d{3})\b`

Comment: But you can just use lookarounds: `(?<!\\w)\\+?380\\d\\d(?:-?\\d+){7}(?!\\w)`. I just do not see any relationship between the example strings and the "working" regex.

Comment: I fix typo in question and check provided solution. None are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difficulty you have is making a word boundary work *before* an optional subpattern `\+?`. With the trailing word boundary, you can use either `\b` or `(?!\w)` (which is only preferable when your context is unknown, but here, you always have an obligatory digit, so, `\b` is enough).

Due to backtracking, `\+?` is "gobbled" and the lookbehind `(?<!\w)` only checks if the first digit is not preceded with a non-word character. Since in `45+38097-12-34-123`, `3` is preceded with a non-word `+`, it is matched.

A solution can be using an alternative in the lookahead:

```
String re = ".*\\+?(?<!\\w|\\w\\+)380\\d\\d(?:-?\\d){7}\\b.*"; 
String s = "45+38097-12-34-123"; 
System.out.println(s.matches(re));
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Qrziz3)

See the [regex demo with your input examples](https://regex101.com/r/lQ2nR1/1).

Comment: Посмотрел на свежую голову. Your solution is right. Official javadoc doesn't explain semantic of `(?<!...|...)` explicitly. My solution `(?:^|\\s)` based on experience with working with Emacs regex, and I believe that it should work with another regex engines. Lookbehind syntax is new to me, there is always room to learn something new. Thanks for support!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I manage to write dumb solution with checking for beginning of string or presents of whitespace:

```
groovy:000> "+38097-12-34-123".matches("(?:^|.*\\s)(\\+?380\\d\\d(?:-?\\d+){7})\\b.*")
===> true
groovy:000> "45+38097-12-34-123".matches("(?:^|.*\\s)(\\+?380\\d\\d(?:-?\\d+){7})\\b.*")
===> false
groovy:000> "45 +38097-12-34-123".matches("(?:^|.*\\s)(\\+?380\\d\\d(?:-?\\d+){7})\\b.*")
===> true
groovy:000> "45 +38097-12-34-123xxx".matches("(?:^|.*\\s)(\\+?380\\d\\d(?:-?\\d+){7})\\b.*")
===> false
groovy:000> "45 +38097-12-34-123 xxx".matches("(?:^|.*\\s)(\\+?380\\d\\d(?:-?\\d+){7})\\b.*")
===> true
```

Final `\b` can be substituted with `(?:\s.*|$)` but groovy shell parser mad about `$` sign (( Have no time to deep into new issue.